# HashSets and MethodInfo

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, hash, methodinfo

I'm writing a routine that performs a bit of reflection. As it proceeds, it performs some validation on encountered `MethodInfo` instances - validating their parameters and return types against some pre-determined contract. This validation is not cheap so I want to record a collection of previously validated methods so that they don't have to be validated again should the routine encounter them more than once.

Should I...

1. Use a `HashSet<MethodInfo>` and add validated `MethodInfo` instances to it.
2. Use a `HashSet<int>` and add the `MethodHandle` of validated methods to it
3. Use a `HashSet<int>` and add the `MetadataToken` of validated methods to it

I am reluctant to choose option 1 because I am not acquiring the `MethodInfo` instances. I have no control over where they come from and wonder whether I might not get multiple instances representing the same method of the same type.

Optionss 2 and 3 seem viable because the entire thing runs within one app-domain. There's little documentation on `MethodHandle` and `MetadataToken` - I don't know when they change, within an app-domain.

Comment: You'll have a hard time getting a warranty here, but `HashSet<RuntimeMethodHandle>` should suffice.